# My border-bottom doesn't disappear when it's on another div class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a question. I have a filtering feature with a button. I have the code below that I'm working on. The problem is, what I want when the button is active, the border-bottom color changes color. In the code that I created, I have managed to provide a condition when it is active. but when I select another button, the border-bottom that is in the previous button is not removed perfectly.

I want the bottom border on the active button to be `#0f0f0f` and on the inactive button to be `#FAFAFA`. Where is the missing code or wrong with my code?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.list-content').css('display','none');
    $('.all').show();
    $('button').on("click" , function(){
        let target = $(this).data('target');
      let content = $('.list-content').data('content');
      
      console.log(target);
      
      $('li#' + target).addClass('active');
      $('.list-content').hide(); 
      $('.' + target).show();
  });
});
```

```css
body{
  background-color:#CACACA;
}

.list-tag ul{
  display:flex;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.list-tag ul li{
  border-bottom: 1px solid #FAFAFA;
}

.list-tag ul li.active{
  border-bottom: 1px solid #0f0f0f;
}

button{
  padding:5px 10px;
  border:none;
  background:transparent;
  boder-bottom:1px solid red;
  cursor:pointer;
}

button:focus{
  outline:none;
  box-shadow:none;
}

.content{
  margin-top:20px;
}
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="list-tag">
      <ul>
        <li id="all">
          <button data-target="all"> All</button>
        </li>
        <li id="tech">
          <button data-target="tech">Tech</button>
        </li>
        <li id="industry">
          <button data-target="industry">Industry</button>
        </li>
        <li id="edu">
          <button data-target="edu">Education</button>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="content">
      <div class="list-content all" id="all">Lorem ipsum All.</div>
      <div class="list-content all" id="all">Lorem ipsum All.</div>
      <div class="list-content all" id="all">Lorem ipsum All.</div>
      <div class="list-content all" id="all">Lorem ipsum All.</div>
      
      <div class="list-content tech" id="tech">Lorem ipsum Tech.</div>
      <div class="list-content tech" id="tech">Lorem ipsum Tech.</div>
      <div class="list-content tech" id="tech">Lorem ipsum Tech.</div>
      <div class="list-content tech" id="tech">Lorem ipsum Tech.</div>
      
      <div class="list-content industry" id="industry">Lorem ipsum Industry.</div>
      <div class="list-content industry" id="industry">Lorem ipsum Industry.</div>
      <div class="list-content industry" id="industry">Lorem ipsum Industry.</div>
      <div class="list-content industry" id="industry">Lorem ipsum Industry.</div>
      
      <div class="list-content edu">Lorem ipsum Edu.</div>
      <div class="list-content edu">Lorem ipsum Edu.</div>
      <div class="list-content edu">Lorem ipsum Edu.</div>
      <div class="list-content edu">Lorem ipsum Edu.</div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't put the border-bottom to the li-element as that will never have the focus-status, here is an example where the border is applied to the button itself. Maybe this works for you:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.list-content').css('display','none');
    $('.all').show();
    $('button').on("click" , function(){
        let target = $(this).data('target');
      let content = $('.list-content').data('content');
      
      console.log(target);
      
      $('li#' + target).addClass('active');
      $('.list-content').hide(); 
      $('.' + target).show();
  });
});
```

```css
body{
  background-color:#CACACA;
}

.list-tag ul{
  display:flex;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}



button{
  padding:5px 10px;
  border:none;
  background:transparent;
  border-bottom:1px solid #FAFAFA;
  cursor:pointer;
}

button:focus{
  outline:none;
  box-shadow:none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #0f0f0f;
}

.content{
  margin-top:20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="list-tag">
      <ul>
        <li id="all">
          <button data-target="all"> All</button>
        </li>
        <li id="tech">
          <button data-target="tech">Tech</button>
        </li>
        <li id="industry">
          <button data-target="industry">Industry</button>
        </li>
        <li id="edu">
          <button data-target="edu">Education</button>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="content">
      <div class="list-content all" id="all">Lorem ipsum All.</div>
      <div class="list-content all" id="all">Lorem ipsum All.</div>
      <div class="list-content all" id="all">Lorem ipsum All.</div>
      <div class="list-content all" id="all">Lorem ipsum All.</div>
      
      <div class="list-content tech" id="tech">Lorem ipsum Tech.</div>
      <div class="list-content tech" id="tech">Lorem ipsum Tech.</div>
      <div class="list-content tech" id="tech">Lorem ipsum Tech.</div>
      <div class="list-content tech" id="tech">Lorem ipsum Tech.</div>
      
      <div class="list-content industry" id="industry">Lorem ipsum Industry.</div>
      <div class="list-content industry" id="industry">Lorem ipsum Industry.</div>
      <div class="list-content industry" id="industry">Lorem ipsum Industry.</div>
      <div class="list-content industry" id="industry">Lorem ipsum Industry.</div>
      
      <div class="list-content edu">Lorem ipsum Edu.</div>
      <div class="list-content edu">Lorem ipsum Edu.</div>
      <div class="list-content edu">Lorem ipsum Edu.</div>
      <div class="list-content edu">Lorem ipsum Edu.</div>
    </div>
```

Just be aware: in your original code the "border-bottom" for the button has a typo "boder-bottom"

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.list-content').css('display','none');
    $('.all').show();
    $('button').on("click" , function(){
        let target = $(this).data('target');
      let content = $('.list-content').data('content');
      
      console.log(target);
      $('li.active').removeClass('active'); // You need to add this line so that it can remove border from active item.
      $('li#' + target).addClass('active');
      $('.list-content').hide(); 
      $('.' + target).show();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the active class from the previous li as you click on a different button.

Couple of ways come to mind to achieve this.

```
    $('.list-content').css('display','none');
    $('.all').show();
    $('button').on("click" , function() {
        let target = $(this).data('target');
        let content = $('.list-content').data('content');

        console.log(target);

        // Add one of these
        // 1. $('li.active').removeClass('active') OR 
        // 2. $(`li:not(#${target})`).removeClass('active')
        $('li#' + target).addClass('active');
        $('.list-content').hide(); 
        $('.' + target).show();
    });
});
```